# Why does the expression x+x not print the same result in the two places it appears?

Tags: java

Why does the expression x+x not print the same result in the two places it appears?

```
   String s = args[0];
   System.out.println("Hello "+s);

   int x = 40;
   System.out.println(x);
   System.out.println(x+x);
   System.out.println(s+" "+x+x);
```

The result of this code is when I execute in cmd `java EG1 kaan`

```
Hello kaan
40
80
kaan4040
```

why is the last result of the print displaying `kaan4040` and not `kaan80`?

Comment: Which of the last two is an arithmetical operation and which is a string concatenation?

Comment: Because one is addition and the other is string concatenation

Answer (score 6):

Because of automatic conversion to String.

On this line you "start printing" an integer, so adding another integer to it will again produce integer that is then converted to String and printed out:

```
System.out.println(x + x); // integer + integer
```

However on this line you "start printing" a String, so all other values you add to it are at first converted to String and then concatenated together:

```
System.out.println(s + " " + x + x); // String + String + integer + integer
```

If you want the two integers to be added together before the concatenation is done, you need to put brackets around it to give it a higher priority:

```
System.out.println(s + " " + (x + x)); // String + String + integer
```

Answer (score 2):

In your last print statement, you are doing a string concatenation instead of an arithmetic addition.

Change `System.out.println(s+" "+x+x)` to `System.out.println(s+" "+(x+x))`.

Comment: To add a little bit explanation... What the result of an operation is depends on the parameters. For example, a String + something else will be a string concatenation while a double + another double will be a double. So you get first a s + " ", which is a String. Then you add s to that String, which will again be a String. And then you again add s to it, further lenghting the String

Answer (score 2):

Make changes `System.out.println(s+" "+x+x);  to System.out.println(s+" "+(x+x));`  Because it need to add the value and then string concatenation

Comment: thank you this really helped

Answer (score 1):

Because java does some work with your code. When you do `System.out.println(x+x);`, it sees `x+x` as an expression with two ints and evaluates it (which is `80`). When you do `""+x+x`, it sees 3 `String`, and thus evaluates this expression as a `String` concatenation.

(btw, by it, I mean javac, and "sees", I mean, well "reads")

Answer (score 0):

Or change print code  to `System.out.println(x +x+" " +s );`

Comment: that might print 80kean or 4040kean :)

Comment: Please explain how the above code works.

Comment: if first expression is String  then compiler see next expression as String after  +  sign. and  + sign works as concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

You are performing concatenation instead of addition

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you append anything to string then it will result to string only.  You have appended `x+x` to `" "` which will append `40` after name. You can use `System.out.println(s+" "+(x+x))`.

Answer (score 0):

On the last print statement:

```
  System.out.println(s+" "+x+x);
```

s is a string and is concatenated with " ", from left to right the expression formed by concatenation with s and " ", is then concatenated with x and then ( s + " " + x ) is concatenated with x, yielding kaan4040.

If the + operator is used with:

- 2 Strings, concatenation occurs
- 1 String and 1 int, concatenation occurs
- 2 ints, arithmetic addition

Consider the following scenario:

```
    System.out.println(x + x +  " " + "hello");
```

In this example 80Kaan is printed as arithmetic addition occurs between x and x, then the resulting value (80) is concatenated with the space and hello.

---

Read from left to right.

---

Answer (score 0):

```
int x = 40;
System.out.println(x);
System.out.println(x + x);
System.out.println("" + x + x);

40
80
4040
```

**40** is int 40

**80** is int 40 + int 40 (Maths)

**4040** is String 40 concat String 40 (because add "" String)

Answer (score 0):

```
   String s = args[0];
   System.out.println("Hello "+s);

   int x = 40;
   System.out.println(x); //1st statement
   System.out.println(x+x); //2nd statement
   System.out.println(s+" "+x+x); //3rd statement
```

The first statement simply converts x into String

The second satatement added the numbers because there aren't strings, the compiler thinks of plus sign as addition of two numbers.

the third one sees that there is a string so the compiler thinks like:

print the value of s, add space(" "), add the value of x (convert x into string), add the value of x (convert x into string ).

Hence, Kaan4040.

If you want to print 80, you can do it in two ways:

```
int sum = x+x; 
System.out.println(s+" "+sum); //more readable code
```

or

```
System.out.println(s+" "+ (x+x) ); //may confuse you
```

the compiler will think of x+x as integers since it doesn't find any string inside the parenthesis. I prefer the first one though. :)

Answer (score 0):

> why is the last result of the print displaying kaan4040 and not kaan80?

This is because this is how String behaves when used with the `+` symbol. and it can mean differently when used in a `println` method.

- It means String ***concatenation*** when you use it with a **String**

  - The 5 even though being an integer will be implicitly converted to String.

**E.g:**

```
System.out.println("Hello" + 5); //Output: Hello5
```

---

- It become mathematical operation:**plus** when used within a pair of brackets because the brackets will be operated first (add first), then convert to String.

  - The **1st** `+` is ***concatenation***, and **2nd** `+` is ***add*** (*Refer to codes below*).

**E.g:**

```
System.out.println("Hello" + (5+7)); //Output: Hello12
```

Answer (score 0):

If any one of the '+' operator operand is string, then java internally create 'StringBuilder' and append those operands to that builder. for example:

```
 String s = "a" + 3 + "c";
```

it's like

```
 String s = new StringBuilder("a").append(3).append("c").toString(); //java internally do this
```